# Reasons of Missing/Corruption of DataBlocks in HDFS File System

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Just want to know the reason of the Missing/Corruption of the Datablocks in HDFS.
Am having a HDFS Cluster of 20Nodes, where 1-Master, 1-HA, 18-Slaves. have removed 3 slaves from the HDFS Location, and after we started the hadoop, error coming as Datablock is missing, while checking found that the Blocks are located in the Slaves which was not removed, even the NameNode Log & Datanode Logs in Master & Slaves are having the entried of the said Datablock saying Hadoop has communicated properly for relocating/resuing the same Blocks, but while check the same Block in the respected slaves i cnt find the Blocks any more.

Is there any reason some how the blocks got removed/deleted without any manual intervence?
Any !dea about the logs which could capture these unrecognized option happend.

Note: Have perform the Node Adding/removing optionion earlier as well, but never face such kind of issue, even also adding back the removed Nodes, the issue was not resolved. Have check in "lost+found" location but the blocks are not available there as well.

I just want to know what all the possible reason could be for the DataBlock removed, and can we perform the tracking of the same.

Thanks & Regards